# Forward traffic from IP6 to IP4

Tags: ipv6, debian-squeeze, ipv4

On my debian6 server is a process that only listen on IPv6 but I also need to listen on IPv4. It seems the program is IPv6 only. Is there a way to route the traffic fom IPv6 to IPv4 on the same host ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens automatically when IPv4-mapped IPv6 is in use.

Check the sysctl `net.ipv6.bindv6only`; if it is set to 0, then IPv4-mapped IPv6 is in use, and incoming IPv4 connections will be mapped and sent to the IPv6 listener.

However, individual processes *can* [override this behavior](http://wiki.treck.com/setsockopt#IPv6_Level_Options) so it's not a cure-all. If you want a specific answer for your circumstance, you'll have to name the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use several reverse proxies which will do this for you (Varnish, HAproxy etc.), in case.

Comment: Adding an example to improve your answer would be great.

Comment: The question was "Is there a way" and not "How do I".